# how to remove the 1sec delay of performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout

Tags: ios, instruments, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I'm using performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout in my ios ui script, and there seems to be a hidden 1 sec delay introduced before executing the command.

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var host = target.host();

var start = new Date().getTime();
var result = host.performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout("/bin/echo", ["Hello World"], 5);
var total = new Date().getTime() - start;

UIALogger.logDebug("duration: " + total);
```

outputs:
duration: 1001

It the same for all commands. Instant when launched from command line, but they have this 1 sec delay when launched via performTask.

Any idea on how to reduce this delay ?

Answer (score 2):

This delay is related to the way UI Automation launches the command internally. There isn't anything we can do from our end.

That said, if you have a lot of commands you are trying to execute in sequence, you can put them all in a shell script and execute it like so:

```
host.performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout("/bin/bash", ["some_shell_script.sh"], 5);
```

That will run the given shell script file within bash and you'll only have to pay the 1 second process startup penalty once.

Answer (score 2):

This has been cleverly solved by the [instruments-without-delay](https://github.com/facebook/instruments-without-delay) project which changes Instruments to remove the 1 second delay in UIAHost.performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout